# Hikari failed with ErrorCode(17002) when running test on unrelated (long) scheduled process

Tags: java, integration-testing, jdbctemplate, spring-test, hikaricp

Where I'm running TestNG test with Spring context:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "development" })
public class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

The test passed or failed correctly, but I'm getting error on irrelevant spring scheduled (takes few seconds to fetch) process which failed to close hikari pool:

```
Thread-4] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext 

- Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4c1d9d4b: startup date [Wed Apr 10 09:40:10 IDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
[Thread-4] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool - Shutdown initiated...
[pool-3-thread-1] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@2e3cdec2 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket closed
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1068)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1015)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:979)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:579)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:408)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:478)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:488)
    at com.package.MyDAO.getScheduleData(MyDAO.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1054)
    ... 26 more
```

My method is:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = TIME)
public synchronized void refresh() {
```

Can we gracefully close hikari pool? If not can this error be ignored in production shutdown also?

Comment: Typically you would not want to have scheduled background tasks running during an integration test. Since you're already using `@ActiveProfiles`, have you tried configuring your beans (e.g., via profiles) in such a way that the scheduled tasks do not get included with your `develompment` [sic] profile?

Comment: Or is "develompment" potentially a typo that should instead read "development"?

Comment: @SamBrannen fix typo in question only. Some scheduled tasks are essential for test